# How to update Restangular model object with server response?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, restangular

My POST and PUT return the current state of entity as seen on the server. How can I tell Restangular to update its model object after the server call?

Just in case - why? Because during save/update the server may have calculated some fields. Because there may have been concurrent updates by other clients and I want to make sure that the client that is currently updating is up to date.

So far I only found this:

```
var res = {foo: "bar"};
var cb = function(response) {
    $.extend(res, response);
}
// POST / create
Restangular.all("resource").post(res).then(cb);

// PUT / update
res.put().then(cb);
```

It seems so dirty and common at the same time that I suspect there must be a better way.

**EDIT**

The code above only demonstrates two distinct actions. My goal is *not* to send update to server after creating the entity, but updating state on client. Synchronizing state with server, if you will.

When I POST an object:

```
var res = {foo: "bar"};
Restangular.all("resource").post(res);
```

Server response has body with:

```
{"foo": "bar", "id": 15}
```

... then I would like Restangular to update and restangularize the `res` object automatically, so it has the ID, can be `put()` etc.

Now a different / complementary scenario. When I PUT a Restangular object:

```
var res = Restangular.one("resource", 15).get();
// returns {foo: "bar", id: 15}
res.put();
```

The server always replies with the current state of the object, which may be:

```
{"foo": "buzz", "id": 15}
```

... so I would like Restangular to update `res` automatically after this PUT.

Comment: Would really like to see a response to this. @mgonto, is there a specific reason why this doesn't happen already? Maybe default REST implementations don't return data after POSTs and PUTs, only a status code?

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee that a RESTy web service will return the object in question after it has been created, altered, etc.  The common form for this is simply: $scope.foo.put().then(function success(newFoo) { $scope.foo = newFoo; }).

Answer (score 4):

I'm the creator of Restangular.

If I understand you correctly, you want to first do the post, and then do the put? In that case you could do something like:

```
var res = {foo: 'bar'};
Restangular.all('resource').post(rest).then(function(response) {
    res = response;
   res.put()
})
```

I don't know if I understood correctly.

Hope it works

Comment: Thank you for the response, it's not my problem though. They are two separate actions. I'll edit the question with more detail.

Comment: I think what he wants is for any server side changes (like updating timestamps or "modified by" type of modifications to the object) to automatically, or easily, update the client object without having to do it from the `.then()`. You can't directly set it since you'd lose any extra model information and have to use something like `$.extend()`

Comment: Hey, after edit you can either do _.extend or use the new feature on Restangular 1.2.0 $object. res = res.put().$object;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
res.put().then(function(data) {
    angular.extend(res, data);
});
```